# Use vTaskList & vTaskGetRunTimeStats() with ESP32, PlatformIO and Arduino Framework

Tags: arduino, esp32, freertos, platformio

I`d like to use *vTaskList* & *vTaskGetRunTimeStats()* on an ESP-32 with PlatformIO and Arduino framework, but get an "undefined reference" error.

If you use google, you will find many hints that it is, or is not (yet) implemented, that you should change some settings in the Espressif IDE (which I don't use) and links to recompile instructions that lead nowhere.

Are there any recent solutions or instructions for this?
Alternatively, are there other solutions to list all tasks and their processor usage (especially IDLE tasks)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want to post your code and *specific* error messages to get any meaningful help.

In this case when you read the documentation on [both](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#vTaskGetRunTimeStats) [functions](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#vTaskList) you will discover that
runtime stats must be explicitly enabled in FreeRTOS before this API becomes available.

When using the Espressif ESP-IDF build configuration (either by invoking the command `idf.py menuconfig` or by manually editing file `sdkconfig`) this is set by config option `CONFIG_FREERTOS_GENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS`. So there would be something like this in `sdkconfig`

```
#
# FreeRTOS
#

...

CONFIG_FREERTOS_GENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS=y
CONFIG_FREERTOS_RUN_TIME_STATS_USING_ESP_TIMER=y

...
```

Comment: The exact error is `undefined reference to vTaskGetRunTimeStats` during linking.

I have also read that both functions have to be activated somehow. As described above I use PlatformIO with the Arduino framework. There is no menuconfig or sdkconfig as far as I know.

Comment: PlatformIO still uses ESP-IDF as its foundation. I leave it up to you to figure out how to find and modify your build configuration - there will be an `sdkconfig` file somewhere under the hood.